# The C* algebra generated by $T$ has no projection?

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $T$ is a self-adjoint operator on a separable infinite dimensional Hilbert space $H$ such that $\|T^2- T\| < 1/4$ .

Prove that there is no (non trivial) projection in $C^*(T)$ the C* algebra generated by $T$ (and just $T$ without $1$)

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Edited question to: there is no projection

Comment: I am not sure why this question has been closed!

Comment: No  context. Questions like "here is my problem. Solve it for me." are usually closed.

Comment: Ok right, even when you can see from the answer that it is not that obvious... do you have a recommended reading you can advise to tackle these kind of questions?

Comment: Any basic text on $C^*$-algebras should have it. But you may want to ask @BazyliZuczek.

Comment: He deleted his answer?? I hope he's not upset...

Comment: Sorry for temporary deletion of the answer. I got some negative points, perhaps due to the fact that the question has been closed.

Comment: It is required that you provide *context*, not necessarily an attempt. A question like this probably didn't come out of nowhere. Among other things, context can help potential answerer in assessing if the claim they are supposed to prove is actually true (it was not in your case).

Comment: @Bazyli but I hope you noticed that your answer doesn't prove the question in general

Comment: What is missing ?

Comment: I changed the question a second time to proving that in general there is no projection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put aside a trivial case, when the $C^*$-algebra generated by $T$ and $I$ is one dimensional, or equivalently the set $\sigma(T)$ consists of a single point $\lambda$ (which satisfies $\lambda^2-\lambda<{1\over 4}).$

Assume that $\sigma(T)=\{\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots, \lambda_n\},$ $n\ge 2.$ Then
$$T=\sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_kP_{\lambda_k},$$ where $P_{\lambda_k}$ denotes the orthogonal projection on ${\rm ker}(T-\lambda_k I).$
Every projection $P_{\lambda_k}$ belongs to the $C^*$-algebra generated by $T$ and $I.$ As $\|T^2-T\|<{1\over 4},$ every eigenvalue should satisfy $\lambda_k^2-\lambda_k<{1\over 4}.$

The statement is not true for infinite dimensional spaces. Consider the Hilbert space $L^2((0,{1\over 4}),dx)$ and the operator $$(Tf)(x)=xf(x).$$ Then $\sigma(T)=\left[0,{1\over 4}\right ],$ therefore $$\sigma(T^2-T)=\left [-{3\over 16},0\right ], \quad \|T^2-T\|={3\over 16}\qquad (*).$$
The $C^*$-algebra generated by $T$ and $I$ is isometrically isomorphic to $C[0,{1\over 4}],$ hence it does not contain any nontrivial projection.
In particular the subalgebra generated just by $T$ has no projections. By the way, this subalgebra is isometrically isomorphic to $C_0\left [0,{1\over 4}\right ],$ the functions which vanish at $x=0.$

In general nontrivial projections exist if and only if the spectrum of $T$ is a not connected subset of $\mathbb{R}.$ For example consider the operator $T$ analogous to the one above, but defined on the space $L^2((0,{1\over 4})\cup ({3\over 4},1),dx).$ Then  $\sigma(T)=\left[0,{1\over 4}\right ]\cup \left[{3\over 4},{1}\right ]$ and $(*)$ holds. The $C^*$-algebra generated by $T$ and $I$ is isometrically isomorphic to $C([0,{1\over 4}]\cup [{3\over 4},1]),$ hence it contains nontrivial projections. The subalgebra generated by $T$ is  isometrically isomorphic to $C_0([0,{1\over 4}]\cup [{3\over 4},1]),$ therefore it also contains a nontrivial projection.

**Remark**. There is nothing special about the constant ${1\over 4}.$ One may consider any positive constant $a>0.$

Comment: maybe the statement is true if we consider just the C* algebra generated by $T$ ?

Comment: I edited my question, thank you for the answer.

Comment: An easier example is to take $T=I$. Then $T^2-T=0$ and $C^*(T)=\mathbb C I$.

Comment: funny night, let me edit further, there is certainly a typo, then we need to prove in general that no projection is in $C^*(T)$

Comment: clearly there is a reason why the $1/4$ is there, or is it just an arbitrary fraction?

Comment: I just noticed you edited your answer, thank you, but still this is not a proof in general that if $T$ is such an operator then $\sigma(T)$ is connected hence there is no projection

Comment: I might miss something here, why is $\sigma(T)$ connected in this problem? from the assumption $\|T^2- T\|<1/4$?

Comment: The assumption does not imply that $\sigma(T)$ is connected. See the last part of my answer. The inequality $\| T^2-T\|<1/4$  is equivalent to $|\lambda^2-\lambda|<{1/4}$ for any $\lambda\in \sigma(T)\subset \mathbb{R},$ which is in turn equivalent to $0<|\lambda  -1/2|<\sqrt{1/2}.$

Comment: oh so you are saying that this question is maybe also wrong

Comment: The question is: determine if the condition implies inexistence of projections. The answer is "no". The condition implies neither  existence nor inexistence.